# TestNG soft assertion output is not comprehensive

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm using TestNG soft assertions in my code like.

```
public class AssertionTest{
  private SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();

    @Test(enabled = true)
    public void testSoftAssertion(){
        softAssert.assertTrue(false);
        softAssert.assertTrue(true); 
        softAssert.assertEquals("India", "US");

        softAssert.assertAll();
    }
}
```

When test execution completes test fails(as expected) but result doesn't give details info, rather it gives info like following which doesn't help to understand which asserts failed.

```
FAILED: testSoftAssertion
java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
null, null
```

I'm expecting output something which will help to understand the result(This type of output is generated when we use hard assertion i.e with `Assert` class).

```
FAILED: testSoftAssertion
java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
expected [true] but found [false]
expected [India] but found [US]
```

Is this known defect/drawback with TestNG soft assertion or there is something, which I'm missing?

Answer (score 10):

you need to provide the failure message while asserting only then it will take up in the report. Consider below code snippet:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

public class SoftAsert
{
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        SoftAssert asert=new SoftAssert();
        asert.assertEquals(false, true,"failed");
        asert.assertEquals(0, 1,"brokedown");
        asert.assertAll();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
FAILED: test
java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
failed, brokedown
```

That is how the softassertions are suppose to work. The intent is to display the error message in case of failure. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: The problem I notice is that it outputs the failed asserts all on one line. So if you have more than just one line of text, it won't look very useful. I'm curious if there's a way to get the formatting going.

Comment: The Best way that i Did was..extending that class and customized it to suite my needs as it was not only about formatting but doing lot more like taking screen shots, logging (pretty format to reports and other places)

Comment: If you find this info useful then accept this as answer so that other searching for similar queries might find it useful

Comment: An update to comment; it looks like the newest version of TestNG actually formats the output correctly. That or I put in a newline somewhere and didn't realize it.

Comment: It put all in one line in old versions only. Already TestNG 6.9.6 has softAssert that makes next line after every fail output. Compare http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.testng/testng/6.9.6/org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert.java?av=f  and http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.testng/testng/6.8/org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert.java?av=f

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you resolved your formatting issues, but TestNG accepts formatting like \n for new lines within Strings (like in Reporting statements). Try taking a look at those kind of options.

Comment: it is not the right way to do the programming. You should reload the assertAll() method and add there ONE \n\t, instead of inserting \n\t to every message. Or use new TestNG, that has this issue corrected, thank authors. Notice, \n is enough for windows only!

Comment: @Gangnus - Do you know any code sample which shows how to make Soft Assert show failures in different lines instead of one line ?

Comment: @testerjoe2 It is another question and should be put here as another question, too. (after searching for among old questions)