# Any way to show assertEquals error message along with the given custom message in TestNg soft assertion

Tags: testng, assertion

Here's a [link to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203274/testng-soft-assertion-output-is-not-comprehensive).

Is there any way to display the default assertEquals error message along with the custom message given in soft assertion?

My requirement is to have custom message and assert error message as below. "broke down expected [1] but found [0]"

```java
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;
    
public class SoftAsert
{
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        SoftAssert asert=new SoftAssert();
        asert.assertEquals(false, true,"failed");
        asert.assertEquals(0, 1,"brokedown");
        asert.assertAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own SoftAssert, this should do the magic:

```
public class MySoftAssert extends Assertion
{
    // LinkedHashMap to preserve the order
    private Map<AssertionError, IAssert> m_errors = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();

    @Override
    public void executeAssert(IAssert a) {
        try {
            a.doAssert();
        } catch(AssertionError ex) {
            onAssertFailure(a, ex);
            m_errors.put(ex, a);
        }
    }

    public void assertAll() {
        if (! m_errors.isEmpty()) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("The following asserts failed:\n");
            boolean first = true;
            for (Map.Entry<AssertionError, IAssert> ae : m_errors.entrySet()) {
                if (first) {
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                sb.append(ae.getKey().getMessage());
            }
            throw new AssertionError(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, seems like it's only the solution for now.